# Razorpay PHP integration Issue

Tags: api, razorpay

I tried to integrate razorpay with my PHP API, according to the document. When creating new object of razorpay API, its return

Razorpay\Api\Api Object ( ). how can i solve it?

1 include the Razorpay PHP SDK

```
 require "include/razorpay/Razorpay.php";  
 $api_key="rzp_test_m60856456456";
 $api_secret="ItemdjzKxvKNBnumasoft"; 
 session_start();
 use Razorpay\Api\Api;
 $api = new Api($api_key, $api_secret);
 print_r($api);
```

Answer (score 0):

After that try to use some methods and print it.

```
$payment = $api->payment->all();
$text =  json_encode($payment->toArray());

print_r($text);
```